# VS Code Tasks: Open Selection

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'v created a task that will open the file that correponds to the path i have selected:

```
{
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Open Selection",
        "command": "myFile=`echo ${workspaceFolder}${selectedText} | sed 's/\\.css/\\.scss/g;s/\\.\\.//g;`;code $myFile",
        "problemMatcher": []
    },
```

I'd like to insert my cursor into an href, do "Expand Selection" then do "Open Selection". But Expand Selection grabs the quotes surrounding the path. I've solved this successfully in Terminal (OS X), but as a VS Code task it fails...

```
"command": "myFile=`echo ${workspaceFolder}${selectedText} | sed 's/\\.css/\\.scss/g;s/\\.\\.//g;s/\\\"//g`;code $myFile"
```

that fails in VS Code. with the error:

```
/bin/bash: command substitution: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

But oddly, when i copy the command that VS Code errors on in out

```
> Executing task: myFile... <
```

and run it in Terminal, it works. So I'm stumped, why a command will succeed in Terminal and fail in VS Code's terminal?

Comment: Is your VSCode terminal different than the terminal? VSCode creates an instance of the terminals on your PC; it doesn't have its own terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, it was user error. Here is the completed task:

```
{
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Open Selection",
        "command": "myFile=`echo echo ${workspaceFolder}${selectedText} | sed 's/\\.css/\\.scss/g; s/\\.\\.//g;s/\\\"//g'`;code $myFile",
    },
```